# To print the value using webdriver when one of the textbox value is changed . But the output is fetched only from the first textbox everytime

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Actual Scenario: I am inserting some values in 2-3 textbox and click on Search button. Based on the value, the page refreshes and it takes 10-20 sec to fetch the value and it is displayed as ->total Log count: 25. I have to print this value but unable to do so.

```
  driver.findElement(By.id("txtMessage")).sendKeys("Push Success");

       driver.findElement(By.id("txtMachineName")).sendKeys("AC204");

       driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys("92");

       driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();

      // use it just before the sendkeys code like this 
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")));

      String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")).getText();
      System.out.println(text);
```

The result is 41 which is fine. But now i want to change

```
       driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys("91");

       driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();
```

The Result is still 41. How i could print the value for 91, 93 ,94 .please help

Answer (score 0):

I would wait for the result to change and store it for each iteration:

```
// store the result
String result = "";

// iterate each value to type
for(String value : new String[]{"82", "73"}) {

    driver.findElement(By.id("txtMachineName")).sendKeys("AC204");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys(value);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();

    // wait for the result to change
    result = wait.until((WebDriver drv) -> {
        String text = drv.findElement(By.xpath("id('dvCount')/span[2]")).getText();
        return text != result ? text : null;
    });

    // print the result
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: // store the result
String result = "";

// iterate each value to type
for(String value : new String[]{"82", "73"}) {

    driver.findElement(By.id("txtMachineName")).sendKeys("AC204");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys(value);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();

    // Code changes

Comment: // Code changes
    result = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")))-> {
        String text = drv.findElement(By.xpath("id('dvCount')/span[2]")).getText();
        return text != result ? text : null;
    });

    // print the result
    System.out.println(result);
}This code shall work . i hav made changes in the wait code and remaining are the same.pls let me know

Comment: Writing code in the comment is not ideal. You should update your question with your findings. Moreover there's is no indication of what you changed and whether it's working or not.